# Best practice for creating 2d graphics assets

Tags: graphics, 2d, assets

As a brief background, I have been slowly chugging away at the core framework of a game I've been wanting to make for some time now. It has gotten to the point where I want to start really fleshing it out with some graphics assets other than colored boxes. And this brings me to the heart of my question:

**What is the best method for creating graphics assets that appear the same quality independent of the device they are drawn on?**

My game is styled after Pokemon, so I want to capture the 16-bit feel while still remaining crisp regardless of the device resolution. Does this mean I just create a ton of duplicate sprite sheets? i.e. a 16x16 32x32 48x48 64x64 version of each asset? Or should I be making vector art and rendering it out specifically for each device? Or is there some other alternative I haven't considered?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If  by 16-bit feel you mean a classic old-school "pixelated" style (but with crisp edges). Then you can just draw them in the minimal dimension and upscale by whatever factor you need using a [Pixel Art Scaling Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_scaling#Pixel_art_scaling_algorithms), the simplest being nearest neighbour. There are of course many algos that produce much nicer results than NN like the 2xSaI and hqx family of algorithms, and RotSprite if you need rotation.

If you want clean antialiased edges you might want to check out this Microsoft Research paper: [Depixelizing Pixel Art](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/kopf/pixelart/)

You can then use these algos as a loading pre-pass for your game.

Alternatively, you could shift them "earlier" into your art pipeline to help speed up generation of multiple (resolution/transform) *variants*, which you could further touch up. This choice largely depends on your level of labor resources and perfectionism. Note also that this loses the "purity" of the solution since it violates DRY because updates will require changes in all variants of a sprite.

I would suggest to first try out some of these upscaling filters and see if you are happy with the results. If you are, you can get away with a loading prepass, which is by far the most desirable outcome because it reduces work and maintenance by a large factor.

Comment: So if I am texturing a triangle with these assets, I should create the minimal dimension asset, at runtime scale it to the appropriate size and finally create the texture with this scaled version?